# Removing event handlers in wpf window

Tags: wpf, event-handling, window

In our wpf app we are adding events in the constructor of our window like this:

```
AddHandler(Keyboard.KeyUpEvent, (KeyEventHandler)HandleKeyDownEvent);

        this.Closing += new System.ComponentModel.CancelEventHandler(WindowF_Closing);
        this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(WindowF_Loaded);
```

Is it a good idea to remove these events in the closing event so that the window is disposed:

```
RemoveHandler(Keyboard.KeyUpEvent, (KeyEventHandler)HandleKeyDownEvent);

        this.Closing -= new System.ComponentModel.CancelEventHandler(WindowF_Closing);
        this.Loaded -= new RoutedEventHandler(WindowF_Loaded);
```

Answer (score 8):

You only need to remove event handlers explicitly if the publisher of the event lives for longer than the subscriber.

In your case, the publisher of the `Closing` and `Loaded` events is the window itself, so there's no need to unsubscribe from the event. The Keyboard, however will be around for a long time, so unsubscribing from the `KeyUpEvent` is a good idea.